# C++ if x more than y by 3

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have an if statement that check if x-variable is more than y-variable by 3... However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

```
if ((x[i] > y) == 3) //if x-variable more than y-variable by 3, execute it
{
    slave_hours[i] == 0;
    slave_no = slave_no - 1;
}
```

Anyone can help out? Thank you

EDIT: I should say by 3 or more

Comment: `if (x[i] > (y +3))`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think OP means exactly 3. Thus, `if (x[i] == (y + 3))`.

Comment: @LogicStuff _"... if x-variable is more ..."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(x[i] > y)` is a boolean, which in this context is casted as an integer (`0` or `1`), but hardly ever reaches `3`. So the branch will always be skipped.

If your values `x[i]` and `y` are integers, just take the difference:

```
if (x[i] - y == 3) {...}
```

If those are floating point numbers, things are getting [more complicated](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/), due to the numbers representation.

EDIT: the same applies to your updated question (`if (x[i] - y >= 3) {...}`), but the floating point concern might be not that important.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your condition to:

```
if (x[i] == (y+3))
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: _... is more than y-variable by 3..._, not equals

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (x[i] > (y + 3))
        {
            //Do this;
        }
        else 
        {
            //Do this;
        }
```

Hope this will help.